# opacity to a div with "background-image" affects the children, I only want to affect the father

Tags: css

I have a `div` that has a `background-image`, I would like its hover effect to change its opacity without affecting the child element, in this case the `<p>`. I have seen similar answers to my question, but having a background does not work the answers. opacity to an element with background affects the children, I only want to affect the father

How can I solve that?

```
<div class="container_img">
  <p>
  this is a text 
  </p>
</div>

.container_img{
   position:relative;
   border:1px solid red;
   margin-top:-14px;
   display: table; 
   margin-top:2px; 
   width: 709px; 
   height: 141px;     
   background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png");
   background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container_img:hover{
 background-color: transparent;
 opacity:0.5;
}
```

this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/t98mbxca/

Answer (score 0):

In this case `opacity` is working as expected as it changes the alpha channel for the element and all of its contents. You may need another approach. Looks like you just want a green gradient button?

I changed the `div` to a `button` and removed the `p` tag in the HTML.

For the background you can use pure CSS to create a `linear-gradient` as a `background-image` using `rgba` for the colors so you can change the alpha (opacity) on hover.

```css
.container_img {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   padding: 0 60px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(130, 167, 99, 1), rgba(102, 146, 63, 1));
}

.container_img:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(130, 167, 99, 0.5), rgba(102, 146, 63, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<button class="container_img">
  this is a text 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you want to use an actual image, is to move your background image to a pseudo element.

```css
.container_img {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: -14px;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 709px;
  height: 141px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container_img::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container_img:hover::before {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_img">
  <p>
    this is a text
  </p>
</div>
```